Cost-effective fulltext search
Have a system which stores semi-structured data - request processing protocols. Currently, it stores the protocols as plain files in a directory hierarchy on a cheap filesystem.
The problem concerns handling issue tracking - completely ad-hoc queries to locate certain protocol. Such queries often involve searching within the unstructured part of the protocol - e.g. a part of an exception message.

Problem size

<10 millions of new data files created daily
~5 queries daily (really just a few cases daily)
semi-structured data
single data file size ranges from 1kiB to ~10s MiB (long processing with many exceptions)
required retention period is several weeks


Current solution
Since the query/write ratio is 5/10M and the data are not fully structured, it didn't make sense to bother with a database system. The running such server + storage wouldn't be effective.
So it is down to using a grep with a few arguments. The queries are definitely not fast but...

Is there a better & cost-effective solution?

Using a "fast grep" alternative? I've heard about ripgrep, etc.
Migrating to a database-like software cheaply indexing the semi-structured data? Running Elasticsearch is $$$ and AFAIK doesn't really handle semi-structured data well OOTB.


You forgot to mention the OS you use - Linux? So the majority of your search queries target on data that is in the un-structured part? If you want to keep the files in file-system storage I would look for tool performs searches multi-threaded - e.g. one thread per core each checking one file. If the hardware of the server has a fast SSD and enough cores that this will speed-up the search speed.

@Robert Yea, the system is Linux. Queries targeting the un-structured part are common, don't known if they are the majority. We don't really target a file-system storage, but so far it seems to be the most cost effective one.

SOLR

is astounding fast at parsing data
can handle unstructured data... basic you'll be using free text search
whilst its parsers can take text in a language like English and tokenize in a way that understands stemming (baby & babies being the same concept), you can avoid this for technical text.  It may require some tuning e.g. if your search would typically enter words: will they appear adjacent or just somewhere.  All this is very configurable.
should your users require being able search via synonyms, this can be supported.
words that add no value to the index can be omitted.  These are called Stop Words.  "the" is an example for English.
you can retain fields used for management of the index, e.g. an entry date, and you could remove based on dates
it can service queries whilst updating the index (some consideration into batching updates in a "commit")
it is not trivial to set up in a clustered environment, but perhaps performance scaling/resilience are not an issue
doesn't need high RAM; it builds indexes on disc


SOLR seems to be in the same class as Elasticsearch/Opensearch aka heavy Lucene-based solutions. Also the unstructured data are rather unfriendly to a generic English tokenizer :) Running such service would be rather costly in order to keep the ingestion ratio, right? Like I said, there are like 5 queries daily...

If you want to stay at a free textual tool, hypergrep is the fastest or one of the fastest grep alternatives. It focuses entirely on speed, unlike e.g. mentioned ripgrep.
